# Как привязать элемент к краю другого элемента?

Tags: javascript, css, анимация

Я не знаю как это объяснить, что бы это было понятно, поэтому прикладываю гифку.
Всё внимание на книгу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может даже не привязать, а просто плавненько поставить её в нужную точку на другом "экране"... как это сделать?

```js
const wrap = document.querySelector('.wrap');
const point = document.querySelector('.point');

wrap.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('sample')) {
    remove_item();

    sample_position = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    const item = create_item(sample_position.left, sample_position.top);
    document.body.append(item);
  }

  wrap.classList.toggle('xxx');
  point.classList.toggle('yyy');
});

function create_item(left, top) {
  const item = document.createElement('div');
  item.classList.add('item');
  item.style.left = `${left}px`;
  item.style.top = `${top}px`;
  return item;
}

function remove_item() {
  const item = document.querySelector('.item');
  if (item) item.remove();
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrap {
  min-width: max-content;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  transition: 1.4s;
}

.wrap>div {
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.left {
  background-color: #505050;
}

.point {
  background-color: #FFEAAB;
  height: 160px;
  width: 10px;
  margin-left: 40%;
  transform: translateX(-100vw);
  transition: 2s;
}

.right {
  background-color: #FF7260;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.sample {
  width: 100px;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: #FFEAAB;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: #9BD7D5;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.xxx {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.yyy {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap xxx">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="point"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="sample"></div>
    <div class="sample"></div>
    <div class="sample"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: это связка ..webgl + js и ещё шейдеры и  на youtube всего один человек это делает ... Юрий Артюх

Comment: тут Костян если захочет покажет

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oz9o вот его видосы посмотри - где то я смотрел это у него

Comment: @MaximLensky тут просто много компонентов, мне кажется это можно на обычных трансформах собрать

Comment: @MaximLensky так, все эти страшные слова нужны, что бы сделать то, что мне нужно, или для всего шаблона в целом? Я думал тут нужна математика, с которой я не подружился

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я уже все сделал кроме книги и фона, но с фонами я думаю разберусь легко

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я видел как Юрий собирал из шейдеров эту шляпу...хотя лично я спорить не буду

Comment: @MaximLensky ну можно как захочется =)

Comment: @MaximLensky конкретно эту ""шляпу"? Просто её выложили всего 2 недели назад, а на канале за последние 2 недели всего 2 видео и они не про это.

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex, а что должно происходить, если кликнуть по третьей книге "Kafka on the Shore" ?

Comment: @qwabra ниже ведь есть пример

Comment: я говорю про прототип, дизайнерский прототип

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Реализовано не все полностью, только позиционирование книжки (`.item`):

```js
const clickHandler = ({ target }) => {
  const bcr = target.getBoundingClientRect(), 
        dX  = bcr.left, 
        vw  = document.documentElement.clientWidth, 
        selected = target.classList.toggle('selected'); 
  if (selected)
    target.style.transform = `translateX(${-dX - vw * 0.6 - bcr.width * 0.5}px) scale(1)`; 
  else
    target.style.transform = ''; 
  target.closest('.container').classList.toggle('has-selected'); 
}; 
for (const itm of document.querySelectorAll('.item')) 
  itm.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
```

```css
html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }

body { width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden; background: #ccc; }

.container { }

.descr, .list {
  position: absolute; 
  transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000); }

.descr {
  top: 15%; right: 10%; 
  width: 50%; height: 70%; 
  transform: translateX(-40vw); 
  transition-delay: 0.25s; 
  background: #fff; }

.list {
  top: 0; left: 100%; 
  display: flex; flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around; align-items: center; 
  width: 100%; height: 100%; 
  transform: translateX(-100%); 
  background: #eee; }

.container.has-selected .descr, 
.container.has-selected .list { transform: translateX(0); }

.list .item {
  flex: 0 0 19vw; height: 28vw; 
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 0 #0004; 
  transform: scale(0.75); 
  transition: none 1s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000); 
  transition-property: transform, opacity; 
  will-change: transform, opacity, box-shadow; 
  background: #fff; }
.list .item.selected { opacity: 0.8; box-shadow: 0 4px 16px 0 #0004; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="descr"></div>
  <div class="list">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
-dX - (vw * 0.6) - (bcr.width * 0.5)
```

Более понятно об этом смещении влево: оно на сумму позиции книжки по X (`dX`), левой координаты блока с описанием (он шириной 50vw и с отступом от правого края в 10vw, поэтому `0.6vw`), и половины ширины книжки (**после** добавления класса с `transform: scale`, как видно по коду).
Вместо ширины вьюпорта можно ширину контейнера использовать, этому ничто не мешает (просто в примере они равны, и решил не усложнять).

Должно нормально работать и с прокручиваемым overflow-hidden списком, но гарантии не дам :Þ

**p.s.:** На клики реагируют только книжки, чтобы лишней логикой листенеров не утяжелять пример.

Comment: Если быстро кликнуть по нескольким книжкам, будет забавно. От этого поможет сброс инлайн-стилей в обработчике клика, но не хочется чинить такую залипательную штуку.

Comment: Я разбирал-разбирал, но так и не понял как подменить книжку на другую как в моем примере и применить уже к ней трансформации. Что здесь поменять: `-dX - (vw * 0.7) - (bcr.width * 0.5)` учитывая что у новой книги есть координата `left`?

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex, Вот эта подмена на другую, мне непонятна... для чего она выполняется? У нас же есть элемент, так почему бы просто не сдвигать его, как на гифке в вопросе? В конце концов, у этого элемента книжки можно сделать дочерний и включить `overflow`, то есть "замену" производить обычным сдвигом внутреннего содержимого. М?

Comment: На эту книгу потом можно нажать, она откроется и в ней будет куча картинок.

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex, В вопросе об этом раскрытии ни слова... Ну, как вариант - можно сделать раскрытие самого элемента книжки (ставим однотонную белую заглушку, меняем размеры), затем загружаем контент в ее внутренний элемент, и `opacity` заглушки плавно снижаем до 0. При закрытии - заглушку опять делаем видимой, убираем контент чтобы снова была видна обложка, плавно сокращаем размеры, и так же плавно прячем заглушку. Либо, для состояния "раскрыта" можно держать отдельный скрытый элемент под контент, и заранее позиционировать его на книжку (поверх нее), но _после_ анимации сдвига.

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex, Пожалуй, отдельным элементом лучше всего: не надо париться с высчитыванием нескольких наборов координат книжки - у нее будет только два состояния (в списке, и после сдвига). Просто берем ее координаты после сдвига, и ставим этот отдельный элемент "поверх" книжки используя `z-index`. Таким образом, можно будет спокойно перемещать/трансформировать этот отдельный элемент, он ведь будет самостоятелен.

Comment: По поводу `left` и подобных свойств... Анимировать позицию и размеры надо _только_ через GPU-ускоренный `transform` (translate и scale) - иначе, для мобильных устройств это тормоза, боль и страдания (не говоря уж о нагреве, повышенном расходе энергии, и донных рейтингах оценки производительности страницы).

Comment: Так я ведь не left анимирую, а от этой точки left делаю трансформацию... В любом случае спасибо за ответы , завтра буду всё пробовать.

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex, А, значит я неправильно понял про `left`. Но не очень понял в чем проблема)) В любом случае, [вот пример раскрытия через отдельный элемент](https://codepen.io/yar85/pen/KKwZGLz). Думаю что такое вполне можно прикрутить к решению в ответе

Comment: Я проспался немного и вспомнил почему я решил создавать книгу отдельно. Дело в том, что у меня реализовано не так как у тебя, на абсолютах, одно над другим, а одно ЗА другим, плюс сам список скролится и у него есть overflow, т.е, я никак не могу иначе книгу с одного экрана перенести на другой, кроме как создать новую и засунуть ее прямо в body. Если бы я увидел этот пример раньше, я возможно сделал бы по-другому, но что есть, то есть. Спасибо еще раз ответы )

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex, Тебе спасибо, за интересную задачку :) В метке [js] сейчас царит уныние, и этот вопрос как глоток чистого воздуха. И да, без абсолютного позиционирования это не решается... сама суть ведь именно в извлечении элемента из потока, а техническая возможность для этого всего одна: через `position`.

Answer (score 1):

Сделал пока вот так, надеюсь кто-нибудь подскажет ещё варианты

```js
const wrap = document.querySelector('.wrap');
const point = document.querySelector('.point');

wrap.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('sample')) {
    remove_item();

    sample_position = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    const item = create_item(sample_position.left, sample_position.top);
    document.body.append(item);
    setTimeout(() => {
      item.style.left = 0;
      item.classList.add('zzz');
    })
  }

  wrap.classList.toggle('xxx');
  point.classList.toggle('yyy');
});

function create_item(left, top) {
  const item = document.createElement('div');
  item.classList.add('item');
  item.style.left = `${left}px`;
  item.style.top = `${top}px`;
  return item;
}

function remove_item() {
  const item = document.querySelector('.item');
  if (item) item.remove();
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrap {
  min-width: max-content;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  transition: 1.4s;
}

.wrap>div {
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.left {
  background-color: #505050;
}

.point {
  background-color: #FFEAAB;
  height: 160px;
  width: 10px;
  margin-left: 40vw;
  transform: translateX(-100vw);
  transition: 2s;
}

.right {
  background-color: #FF7260;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.sample {
  width: 100px;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: #FFEAAB;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: #9BD7D5;
  transition: all 2s;
}

.xxx {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.yyy {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.zzz {
  transform: translateX(40vw);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap xxx">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="point"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="sample"></div>
    <div class="sample"></div>
    <div class="sample"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```